# Android TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener not working in camera API 2

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I have using Camera API 2 last 3 Year all is work perfect but recently previous 10 days is not working.  Currently *TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener* is not called so camera preview is not open, open is a black screen. What is a problem or any update in related camera API2 . Please find the code below...

```
  textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
    assert textureView != null;
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);


TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {   //open your camera here
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {   // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
    Log.e("onSurfaceTexture","onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        Log.e("onSurfaceTexture","onSurfaceTextureDestroyed");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        Log.e("onSurfaceTextureUpdated","onSurfaceTextureUpdated");
    }
};
```

In the above code working perfectly last 3 year but in previous 10 days ***TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener*** does not work so ***openCamera*** method is not called, so show a black screen. Please suggest any idea of how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but my problem is resolved by adding a single line on manifest file i.e.  android:hardwareAccelerated="true".